# Appending to a multi-dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, loops, multidimensional-array

I have this code:

```
philips_trousers = []
for i in range(0, 5):
  philips_trousers.append(["T"] * 5)
  philips_trousers.append(["R"] * 5)
  philips_trousers.append(["O"] * 5)
  philips_trousers.append(["U"] * 5)
  philips_trousers.append(["S"] * 5)
  philips_trousers.append(["E"] * 5)
  philips_trousers.append(["R"] * 5)
  philips_trousers.append(["S"] * 5)
print philips_trousers
```

Which outputs the following:

```
[['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'], ['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U'], ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S'], ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'], ['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R'], ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S'], ['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'], ['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U'], ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S'], ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'], ['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R'], ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S'], ['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'], ['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U'], ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S'], ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'], ['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R'], ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S'], ['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'], ['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U'], ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S'], ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'], ['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R'], ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S'], ['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'], ['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U'], ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S'], ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'], ['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R'], ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S']]
```

So far so good you're probably thinking, but I'm wondering something -- why does Python fill `philips_trousers` in quite the way it does? That is, why does the `append()` function create new child arrays with the form `['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T']`, `['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R']` etc, rather than: `['T', 'R', 'O', 'U', 'S', 'E', 'R', 'S']`?

Comment: Why would you expect `['T', 'R', 'O', 'U', 'S', 'E', 'R', 'S']`?

Comment: Hhhhhmmm, it's difficult to put into words, but I think I expected it to create five child arrays and populate them with ["T"], then append ["R"] to those arrays, and so on and so forth.

Comment: You're calling `append` on the `philips_trousers` list, not on its sublists. You're not going to append to the list's sublists.

Comment: So... I think the sticking point for me is this: where in the code does it end one child array (say ```['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R']```) and begin another (say ```['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']```)? That's the bit which doesn't make sense to me. What instruction am I passing to the compiler that causes it to end one child array and begin another?

Comment: `["T"] * 5` is one list. `["R"] * 5` is another. Nothing here would stick them together.

Comment: So... they're separate *lists* within a single array because I'm appending *within* the array```philips_trousers```, but the actual lists have nothing to do with each other (other than sharing a parent array)? I think this has helped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`["T"] + ["T"]` is the same thing as `["T", "T"]`.  Multiplication is just addition several times.  Therefore, `["T"] * 5` is the same thing as `["T", "T", "T", "T", "T"]`<sup>1</sup>.  What you see in your end list is several of such lists.  If you want a bunch of `["T", "R", "O", ...]`, you can do this:

```
philips_trousers = []

for _ in range(5):
    philips_trousers.append(list("TROUSERS"))

print philips_trousers
```

which is pretty much the shorter version of Remuze's answer.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Don't use list multiplication with mutable objects because each item in the list will be the *same object*.  That means that modifying one will modify them all.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`["T"] * 5` first gets converted into `[['T'],['T'],['T'],['T'],['T']]`, which is then appended on to the empty array. The same then happens for each of the other letters.

To get the functionality you are looking for, you should try this:

```
philipsTrousers = []
for i in range(0, 5):
  philipsTrousers.append(["T","R","O","U","S","E","R","S"])
print philipsTrousers
```

Comment: Well, no... `[T] * 5` isn't valid (no quotes) and `["T"] * 5` creates a single list containing 5 "T"s; not 5 lists containing a single "T" in a list of lists. To get `[['T'],['T'],['T'],['T'],['T']]` you'll need `[["T"]] * 5`